# Java Has-a relationship with List<ObjectA>

Tags: java, list, object, inheritance, relationships

So im trying to get my head round the has-a relationship between classes and Id like some help with one instance:

```
public class Test{
List<ObjectA> list;
}
```

Is this 
Test has-a List or
Test has-a List<> or
Test has-a ObjectA or
Test has-a List<> and has-a ObjectA

Any help welcome???

Answer (score 0):

I would say "`Test` has-a List of references to `ObjectA`".

If `Test` owns those objects, a better way might be "`Test` has zero or more `ObjectA`".

Answer (score 0):

Test has a List and list can contain Objects. We cannot say Test has an Object.